# Reference in java

Tags: java, oop

```
class foo {
    public int a = 3;
    public void addFive() {
        a += 5;
        System.out.println("f");
    }
}

class Bar extends foo {
    public int a = 8;
    public void addFive() {
        this.a += 5;
        System.out.print("b");
    }
}

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        foo f = new Bar();
        f.addFive();
        System.out.println(f.a);
    }
}
```

I can't get how 3 comes. I thought that the resort is "b 13". Bar is in f, isn't it? Why f.addfive() comes from bar? But f.a comes from foo?

Comment: You asked for a `Bar`, not a `foo`. It should be `13`. `Bar#addFive` overrides what is in `foo#addFive`. If you want the answer to be `8`, then call `super().addFive` instead.

Comment: Look into field hiding.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Possible duplicate? It is exactly the same!

Comment: Methods are looked up at runtime while fields are not. Since your `f` is of (static) type `foo`, you get `foo`’s value of `a` when doing `f.a`. You could cast to Bar (`((Bar)f).a`) to get `Bar`’s a. But since the runtime type of `f` is `Bar`, it’s `Bar`’s `addFive` method that gets called. That’s one of the reasons most fields are marked private and there are getter and setter methods.

Answer (score 0):

Bar extends foo and method addFive() is overridden. Which method will be invoked when there are overridden methods is decided at runtime. If you change the name of the methods, for example addFive1() and addFive2() (the latter for class bar), the addFive2() method will be called.The variable a is declared in foo, that's why it comes from this class.

Try reading some books. Effective Java, Java the complete reference etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is three scope of variables in java.

1. instance variables
2. parameter variables
3. local variables

These variables have different piority according to place. local and parameter variables are only exist while run it`s containing methods. So you can read more about it from http://www.cs.umd.edu/~clin/MoreJava/Objects/local.html article.